# Is there an AND operations on ignore/favorite lists (possible feature request)

Tags: feature-request, tagging

I just started using tags and I was wonder if there was an AND type of operations. So, for example, suppose I have no problem homework or calculus but I am tired of seeing calculus and homework so I would add something like "(calculus $\land$ homework)" to my ignore list. This makes it so if a question has the homework tag but not the calculus tag I could still see it. Does something like that already exist? If not I would like to request this feature.

Comment: No, it does not currently exist. It's a reasonable feature request, though unlikely to be implemented (as most feature requests are). Are you open to the possibility of using a userscript/extension in your browser to the same effect?

Comment: @ˈjuː.zɚ79365 I would be willing to use an extension to get the same effect. Is there one that does this already?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ignored questions are hidden on the client side: they are present on pages you load from SE, but get hidden by a script. So it makes sense to use another client-side script to make the filtering smarter. The script below improves on the built-in mechanism in two ways:

- it is possible to ignore tag combinations such as `homework` AND `calculus`
- a question that has at least one of your favorite tags will not be hidden

The list of ignored tags should be entered as the variable `ignored`, separated by commas. Each must be preceded by `.t-`: for example, `.t-big-list, .t-analysis`. To ignore a tag combination, concatenate two (or more) tags: `.t-homework.t-calculus`. See the second line here:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var ignored = '.t-homework.t-calculus, .t-analysis, .t-soft-question';
  $('.question-summary').each(function() {
    if (!question.is('.tagged-interesting')) {
    var question = $(this); 
    question.find('.tags').each(function() {
      if ($(this).is(ignored)) { question.css('display', 'none'); }
  }); } }); });
```

To make this script run in your browser, some extra work is needed. One option is to turn it into userscript by adding a metablock, as is done below. I tested this userscript under   Greasemonkey in Firefox.

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        Hide questions
// @namespace   Math.SE scripts
// @description ignored = '.t-A.t-B, .t-C' hides (A AND B) OR C
// @include     http://math.stackexchange.com/*
// @require     http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js
// @grant       none
// @version     1
// ==/UserScript==

$(document).ready(function() {
  var ignored = '.t-homework.t-calculus, .t-analysis, .t-soft-question';
  $('.question-summary').each(function() {
    if (!question.is('.tagged-interesting')) {
    var question = $(this); 
    question.find('.tags').each(function() {
      if ($(this).is(ignored)) { question.css('display', 'none'); }
  }); } }); });
```

Although in principle Chrome can take userscripts, automatically converting them into extensions, `@require` is problematic (at least for me). One possibility (untested) is to use Tampermonkey. Another is to turn the script into [self-contained extension](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/29863189/smart_hide.zip) (see readme.txt for installation steps).

Comment: Cool. It works, I am using the self-contained extension. I will see if I can figure out one of the monkeys, as it seems like it would be easier to manage that way, later.